# Get a value from an input textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, textarea

Okay. So I have this code

```
<input id="suspect" value="" type="text">
<input id="reason" value="" type="text">
<textarea></textarea>
var suspect = $('input#suspect').text();
var reason = $('input#reason').text();
$('textarea').val('' + suspect + ' and ' + reason + '')
```

Then I put something in both of those 2 inputs and then the textarea recieves no value from the inputs. How to fix that problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you set the variables there's no text inside the elements from which you're trying to recover the entered-text (incidentally, for inputs you're looking for `.val()`). If you bind to the `focus` event:

```
$('textarea').focus(
    function(){
        var suspect = $('#suspect').val(),
            reason = $('#reason').val();
        $(this).val('' + suspect + ' and ' + reason + '');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pg85w/).

Also, in this case (since you've placed the JavaScript *after* the elements in the DOM, albeit you've omitted the `<script></script>` tags) you might be okay not using the `$(document).ready()` event handler, but I'd normally suggest wrapping jQuery in such, just to be sure that events are being bound *after* the elements to *which* they're being bound exist in the DOM.

References:

- [`focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Awesome; you're very welcome, and I'm glad to have been of help! =)

Answer (score 1):

- `.text()` -- Gets the text inside the elements
- `.val()` -- Gets the ***value*** of the elements

Since the text is stored inside the `value`, therefore you should use `.val()` instead of `.text()`.

```
var suspect = $('input#suspect').val(),
    reason = $('input#reason').val();
$("textarea").val(suspect+" and "+reason);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want instant change try the keyboard events

```
$(window).keyup(function() {
var suspect = $('input#suspect').val();
var reason = $('input#reason').val();
$('textarea').val('' + suspect + ' and ' + reason + '');
});
```

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/TtAVS/

​

Answer (score 0):

should use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get value from the input box

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `val()` here instead of `text()`, and there also needs to be some kind of event (like a click) that causes the data to be extracted from the inputs and put into the textarea.

It also might be worth noting that since id's are unique,

```
var suspect = $('#suspect').val();
var reason = $('#reason').val();
```

are sufficient as selectors and (I find) easier to read.